# UIDeviceOrientation *orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation; gets an 'incomplatible types in initialization' error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

can anyone tell me why this line would throw an incompatible types error?

```
UIDeviceOrientation *orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not returning a pointer:

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
```